# Cursor focus after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

The idea is that I have two text fields and after I move from one field to another field the page refresh is done and there is no focus afterwards on the second field. I need to put cursor to the second field where it was previously before page update. Can somebody please tell me how to fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't understand want you want to do ? if you have two input fields then when page reload what happen . please clear Query concept or add some code what you want to do . .

Comment: Is your first field empty after your page refresh? I think you want to submit a form. So you have to check if your data is not empty. Have you thought about ajax?

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#textbox1').val()) {
    $('#textbox2').focus();
}
```

You can do something like this, but need to take care of edit case (if any), so the condition can be anything as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the empty field in document.ready and focus on it with .focus().

After filling your first field check both fields and focus on empty one.So on first page load it will focus on your first field and after second load it will focus on you second field.